# red5 with s3(i want to customize the path for streaming videos)

Tags: red5

I am using *red5* for streaming videos in my project and I am able to play the videos from the local system which are saved in default folder "streams".

Now i want to customize the path and want to get the videos from S3. How do i configure red5 to work with S3. Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

I've got code using the IStreamFilenameGenerator works with S3; I'll warn you now that it may not work with the latest jets3 library, but you'll get the point of how it works by looking through the source. One problem / issue that you must understand when using S3 is that you cannot "record" to the bucket on-the-fly; your flv files can only be transferred to S3 once the file is finalized; there is an example upload call in the Application.class. Whereas "play" from S3 will work as expected.

I added the S3 code to the red5-examples repo: https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples

Comment: How does recordPath get set? It is not set in your example code and not part of the interface. Also, why are these values static? Does Red5 start a a new VM per stream?

Comment: Red5 uses the Spring Framework and most properties, classes, settings are set using dependency injection.

Comment: The source of my confusion was around the missing apis. Seems like things have changed on the head of the git repo. IBroadcastStream doesn't even exist anymore

Comment: Latest version is here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/server/api/stream/IBroadcastStream.java

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Also, is seems a bit unsafe to depend on a static for the recordPath, is that guaranteed to be the same for all instances?

Comment: A static will be the same for all instances in the same vm.

Comment: Yes. But you are using a non static method to set a static variable. This non static function appears to be called whenever a new instance of the class is created. This means that the value of that static could be inconsistent and not thread safe.

Comment: Do you know where to find ActionScript files for any of the examples, i.e. VOD or publisher? I've only been able to find compiled versions...

Comment: I found that earlier. The only AS file is a the player4, tons of others that are only fla. I'm like to implement a recorder/player with ui in html and send events via javascript.

Comment: The older apps were all or mostly in the fla file; if you look in the classes directory, you'll find the "missing" code

Comment: Thanks! I found them.

Comment: Is there a coresponding server side example for messagerecorder?

Comment: Has anyone been able to get this example to work?  I'm manually hard coding the file name to the full path of my S3 file, and it's not working (tried with and without http:// preface).  If I set the filename to the full path on my local file system it works fine.   In the sample, I'm not really seeing the path string builder creating the full path to the S3 file.  Am I misunderstanding the sample?  I can see how its persisting the recording via upload, but I'm only seeing the playback constructing a playback path/filename that is local.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Search for:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IStreamFilenameGenerator

Or https://www.google.com.au/search?q=IStreamFilenameGenerator+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a

and you will find some examples howto modify the path(s).

You could alternatively also of course simply mount some drive into the streams folder or I guess a symbolic link would even work. But it might be not that flexible as if you can do it with IStreamFilenameGenerator and generate really some string completely like you want it.

Sebastian

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried with IStreamFilenameGenerator but iam strucked it says it could not find the URL in the system.The below is my code snippet.

Comment: public class CustomFileGenerator implements IStreamFilenameGenerator {
 private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DemoServiceImpl.class);
 
  /** Path to get streams... */ 
  public String playbackPath = "http://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/"; 
 
  /** Set if the path is absolute or relative */ 
  public boolean resolvesAbsolutePath = false; 
 
 @Override
 public String generateFilename(IScope scope, String name, GenerationType type) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return generateFilename(scope, name, null, type); 
 }

Comment: @Override
 public String generateFilename(IScope scope, String name, String extension, GenerationType type) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String filename; 
     filename = playbackPath + name; 
     log.debug("######################"+playbackPath);
     log.debug("*****************************"+filename);
    if (extension != null) 
     // Add extension 
     filename += extension; 
    return filename; 
 }

Comment: @Override
 public boolean resolvesToAbsolutePath() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return resolvesAbsolutePath; 
 }
 /*public void setRecordPath(String path) { 
   recordPath = path; 
  } */
  public void setPlaybackPath(String path) { 
   playbackPath = path; 
  } 
  public void setAbsolutePath(Boolean absolute) { 
   resolvesAbsolutePath = absolute; 
  } 
}